# Удаление точки при клике по кнопке на балуне

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Добавляю точки на карту Yandex Maps, по клику на точку должен открываться балун, где будет кнопка удаления метки.
Нашел работающий [метод](http://dimik.github.io/ymaps/examples/placemark-balloon-layout/) на версии API 2.0, но на 2.1 это не работает...

Answer (score 0):

В API 2.1 есть [метод `setCoordinates()`](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/IPolygonGeometryAccess-docpage/?from=SO#setCoordinates), который позволяет задать новые координаты геометрии.

В вашем случае нужно по нажатию кнопки в балуне передавать в этот метод координаты без вершины, которую необходимо удалить.

Answer (score 0):

Получилось реализовать, запоминая добавленные точки в массиве:

```
var new_point_arr = [];
$('.add_new_point').click(function(){
    var tmp = new ymaps.Placemark(res.geoObjects.get(0).geometry.getCoordinates(), {
                balloonContent: '<button class="delete_new_point" data-new_point_id="' + new_point_arr.length + '">Удалить</button>'
            }, {});
            new_point_arr.push(tmp);
            myMap.geoObjects.add(tmp);
        }
});

$('body').on('click', '.delete_new_point', function(e){
    myMap.geoObjects.remove(new_point_arr[$(this).data('new_point_id')]);
});
```